# how can I fix this Error, This relative module was not found?

Tags: vue.js

**I'm trying to add background image to my app**

```
#app {
  background-image: url('./assets/cold-bg.jpg');
}
```

**then I get this error**

```
* ./assets/cold-bg.jpg in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=css
```

Comment: Need more info about the setup. Where is that css rule is placed?  Are you using some framework like Vuetify or Nuxt there?

Answer (score 0):

I quick fix to this error which I always use is loading the image with computed property, with this approach JavaScript will get the correct path for me no matter how nested my components is.

E.g.

```
computed: {
    getImage() {
        return "background-image:url(" + require("@/assets/cold-bg.jpg") + ")";
    }
```

Then in your template, you can then use it as follows:

```
<template>
    <div :style="getImage"></div>
</template>
```

You can notice that I proceeded `@/` to the image src, that tells `vue` compiler to look up through the **src** folder.

You can use `methods` instead of  computed property, this will help load the image src you pass as parameter.

E.g.

```
methods: {
    getImage(path) {
        return "background-image:url(" + require("@/" + path) + ")";
    }
```

In your template, pass the correct path to the method.

```
<template>
    <div :style="getImage('assets/cold-bg.jpg')"></div>
</template>
```